# Bootstrap responsive embed not working as expected

Tags: html, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube-iframe-api

embedding video in grid system of Bootstrap 3.1, video is not expanding full width of the grid column. How to make it 100% wide to the parent column keeping the aspect ratio?
Also, even if I use a 4:3 video, it appears very wide in the browser with very short height. 
here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
   .
   <!-- other items-->
   .
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gYhi3pAiQY4"></iframe>
            </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure `embed-responsive` wasn't added until 3.2. Try updating.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yolalu/1/edit -- yes, @Rob is correct. Responsive embed wasn't added until a couple weeks ago or so with 3.2

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob and BootstrapThemer....  It worked :)

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Rob said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142692/bootstrap-responsive-embed-not-working-as-expected#comment39137926_25142692):

> Pretty sure embed-responsive wasn't added until 3.2. Try updating.

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to update, for one reason or another, you can add the styles yourself.  It's fairly straight forward.  Here's the SASS:

```
// Embeds responsive
//
// Credit: Nicolas Gallagher and SUIT CSS.

.embed-responsive {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  .embed-responsive-item,
  iframe,
  embed,
  object,
  video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
  }
}

// Modifier class for 16:9 aspect ratio
.embed-responsive-16by9 {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

// Modifier class for 4:3 aspect ratio
.embed-responsive-4by3 {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}
```